addLiquidityETH reverts even after token approval
I am trying to deploy liquidity on a testnet using this code. However, it reverts with no explanation given other than that error. According to the UniswapV2 docs, I am using the correct router (confirmed via debugging), the pair will automatically be created via this method (since it doesn't exist yet), and all the other variables are correct. The contract has enough ETH and tokens and it still doesn't work. The amount of ETH and tokens at the time this code runs is the amount that the contract actually has.
function provideLiquidity(address tokenAddress, address router) internal {
        TokenData storage data = tokenData[tokenAddress];

        uint256 tokenAmount = data.token.balanceOf(address(this));
        uint256 ethAmount = data.collectedEth;

        data.token.approve(router, tokenAmount);

        IUniswapV2Router02(router).addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(data.token),
            tokenAmount,
            0,
            0,
            lpAddress,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

Just to be extra clear - my contract exchanges tokens for ETH. Once enough ETH is collected (e.g. 1.0 ETH), then provideLiquidity is called in that same transaction that is providing the last ETH needed. So contract has 0 ETH -> txn with 1 ETH -> sends tokens to that person -> calls provideLiquidity immediately after, providing that 1 ETH + all the tokens remaining in the contract's balance. I don't see why this would be an issue as other tokens do the same thing though.
EDIT: It turns out that the Uniswap documentation had the wrong router address specifically for Sepolia. For anyone else trying to deploy on Sepolia, you can use 0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008 (this is not the official address and might be modified, someone else deployed it for testing but it's enough for my usecase)

Do you have a hash of a failure? Cannot see obvious issue just from what you posted, other than where it says lpAddress, your probably want your contracts/self address. Unless you are burning the lp by sending it to the lp contract, or that address is actually your contract and not the pool address.

It turns out that the Uniswap documentation had the wrong router address specifically for Sepolia. For anyone else trying to deploy on Sepolia, you can use 0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008 (this is not the official address and might be modified, someone else deployed it for testing but it's enough for my usecase)

A lot of the addresses on their deployment pages are dummy or empty. Also a reminder that adding specific values like addresses, amounts, or a failed hash, can help when asking these questions. That would be picked up instantly.
